# Sequelize ORM: Make a OR operator inside and operators

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to produce this query in Sequelize:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE (to_user_id = 1 AND from_user_id = 2)
OR (to_user_id = 2 AND from_user_id = 1)
ORDER BY "createdAt"
```

I try this way:

```
const messages: Messages[] = await this.messages.findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            [Op.and]: [{ to_user_id: toUserId }, { from_user_id: fromUserId }],
            [Op.and]: [{ to_user_id: fromUserId }, { from_user_id: toUserId }]
          }
        ]
      },
      attributes: {
        exclude: ['deletedAt']
      }
});
```

But is making this query:

```
SELECT "id", "from_user_id", "to_user_id", "body", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "messages" AS "messages" WHERE ("messages"."deletedAt" IS NULL AND (("messages"."to_user_id" = 2 AND "messages"."from_user_id" = 1)))
```

Why my OR operator is not being applied in this two and operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use separate objects for AND conditions like this:

```
const messages: Messages[] = await this.messages.findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            [Op.and]: [{ to_user_id: toUserId }, { from_user_id: fromUserId }]
          },
          }
            [Op.and]: [{ to_user_id: fromUserId }, { from_user_id: toUserId }]
          }
        ]
      },
      attributes: {
        exclude: ['deletedAt']
      }
});
```